# Styling text with dynamically span does not work

Tags: java, android

I want to dynamically change the textsize and the style of a string:

```
private Spannable styleSpan(String string, int style) {
    Spannable sb = new SpannableString( string );
    sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(style), 0, string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
    return sb;
}

private Spannable changeSize(String string, int size) {
    Spannable sb = new SpannableString( string );
    sb.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(size), 0, string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
    return sb;
}
```

Now I have this string:

```
date = TextUtils.concat(styleSpan(startDay, android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD)+"."+startMonth+" "+
        changeSize(startHour, 40)+":"+changeSize(startMinute, 40)+" → "+changeSize(endHour, 50)+
        ":"+changeSize(endMinute, 50)).toString();
dateTime.setText(date); // is a TextView
```

But for some reason, the text is not styled at all.

Comment: you are using `... +"."+startMonth+" "+ ...` which clears all spans

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: using some `Spannable` builder?